# How can I close an auction when the closing time is reached?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am developing a real-time auction site for a school project. We can't make any changes to the design of the database. 
The 'Item' table has a column for the expiration date (the day the auction expires) and the expiration time (the exact time at which the auction expires). It also has a column that indicates whether the auction is opened or closed. This [AuctionClosed?] column needs to be updated when the expiration date and time are reached, which has to happen in real-time.

We're using an SQL Server database and the website runs on PHP7. The only possible solution I've found is to run a job every second, but this is too much overhead.

This is the function I want to use to check the column:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_isAuctionClosed (@Item BIGINT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @expirationDay DATE = (SELECT expirationDate FROM Item WHERE itemId = @Item)
  DECLARE @expirationTime TIME = (SELECT expirationTime FROM Item WHERE itemId = @Item)

  IF 
  DATE(GETDATE()) = @expirationDay AND TIME(GETDATE()) >= @expirationTime
  OR
  DATE(GETDATE()) > @expirationDay
  RETURN 1

  RETURN 0
END
```

And this is the procedure that updates the column:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateAuctionClosed @Item BIGINT
AS
UPDATE Item
SET [AuctionClosed?] = fn_isAuctionClosed(@Item)
WHERE itemId = @Item
```

Comment: Use a calculated column instead. You can't cause an SP to run when a specific time is reached.

Comment: But this calculated column doesn't update in real-time right? Do you mean a DEFAULT constraint?

Comment: As the column would rely on `GETDATE()`, so can't use the `PERSISTED` property, it would be calculated at runtime every time the column is referenced.

Comment: Alright I'm gonna try this out, thank you very much! So do I use a DEFAULT constraint for this?

Comment: Your `dbo.fn_isAuctionClosed` function is not correct anyway. If the auction closed at 17:00 on 1st April and the function was queried at 09:00  on 2nd April it would say that the auction was still open as the time of day is less

Comment: I updated it now, would this work?

Comment: @Memthene no, as `DATE()` isn't a recognised function in SQL Server (neither is `TIME()`). To convert to a date in SQL Server you need to use `CONVERT`: `CONVERT(date, YourDateColumn)`

Comment: Ah, I was confusing it with the YEAR() and DAY() functions, I assumed there would be functions that took the DATE out of a DATETIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific, what you really want here is a calculated column. Like I said in the comments, as the column will rely on the current date and time, the column won't be deterministic. This means it can't be `PERSISTED` but would be calculated every time the column is referenced (A `PERSISTED` column actually has it's value stored and is calculated when the row is effected in some way and restored). Even so, it can be calculated as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Item DROP COLUMN [AuctionClosed?]; --You can't alter a column to a computed column, so we have to DROP it first

ALTER TABLE Item ADD [AuctionClosed?] AS CASE WHEN CONVERT(datetime,expirationDate) + CONVERT(datetime, expirationTime) > GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

On a side note, I recommend against special characters in an object's name. Stick to alphanumerical characters only, and (if you must) underscores (`_`), as these don't force the object to be delimit identified.

Comment: I agree on the special characters part, unfortunately we have to stick to the table/column names that were in the design :(

Comment: Which data type will the [AuctionClosed?] column use when you add it this way? Does it automatically use a BIT?

Comment: It would be an `int` in the above, as that's the default datatype for a literal integer value in SQL Server. If you specifically want it to be a `bit`, wrap the whole expression in a `CONVERT`/`CAST` to a `bit`.